# How to get list of tweets that share the same story but the URLs might be different in each tweet

Tags: twitter, sna

I am interested in finding all tweets that share a given url (e.g. [this story](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/24/health/without-lucrative-market-potential-ebola-vaccine-was-shelved-for-years.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&version=HpSum&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=0)). I am not looking for how many re-tweets a single tweet gets or how many times a page is shared on Twitter (i.e. look at the page's social shares counter). Instead, I am trying to figure out how many unique tweets shared a story where the url in the tweets might be different but each tweet is pointing to the same webpage/story. So for the story I linked to above, can I get a list of all tweets that link to that NY Times article?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

I can link to that article with shortened URLs from several sites, and it will still point to the same article.

In order to find all of the links that point to the same story, you would have to parse EVERY tweet with a shortened URL.  Then, you would have to write code that calls each of the URLs to see which point to the page you're talking about.

You would have to parse millions of tweets a day, and access to Twitter's stream in those volumes is restricted.